# How to create my own binomial coefficient function in R

Tags: r, factorial, binomial-coefficients

I have created a factorial function which is then used to create a function for the binomial coefficient. My factorial function works but the binomial function does not.

I needed to create a factorial function which was then to be used to create a binomial coefficient function using R. 
I was not allowed to use the base program's functions such as factorial nor choose. 
I had to use for statements, logics etc. even though it is inefficient.

I had to print the factorial of zero and ten, then the binomial coefficient with n = 5, and k = 2

```
fact <- function(n) {
  x <- 1 
  if(n == 0) {
    print(1)
  } else {
    for(i in 1:n) { 
      x <- x*i
    }
  }
  print(x)
}

fact(0)
fact(10)

bc <- function(n, k) {
  y <- fact(n) / fact(n - k) * fact(k)
  print(y)
}

bc(5, 2)
```

For the factorial function I got the correct answer

But for the binomial function I was way off.

If someone can show me where I have made the mistake I would be most appreciative.

Comment: sounds like homework?

Comment: I think you probably want `fact(n)/(fact(n-k)*fact(k))`. R is just following the order of operations, and doesn't know that those terms are both supposed to be in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues here, both relating to basic R coding and coding in general. Let's go through some of them step-by-step:

1. Your function `fact` actually does not return anything. All it does at the moment is `print` values to the console. If you take a look at `help("print")` it is stated that

   > ‘print’ prints its argument and returns it *invisibly* (via ‘invisible(x)’).

   So in order for `fact` to actually return a value we can do

   ```
   fact <- function(n) {
      x <- 1
      if (n > 0) {
          for (i in 1:n) x <- x * i
      }
      return(x)
   }
   ```

   I have tidied up your code by removing the unnecessary `n == 0` check.

   Note that there is still room for improvement. For example, there are better ways to calculate the factorial of a number. Secondly, your function currently does not properly deal with negative numbers. Generally, the factorial is only defined for non-negative integers. So you can either change `fact` to return `NA` for negative numbers, or -- perhaps more interesting -- generalise the factorial function to the Gamma function to allow for any real (or even complex) number. Either way, I'll leave this up to you.
2. Similarly your function `bc` also does not return anything, and instead writes the value of `y` to the console. Furthermore you need to be careful of brackets to make sure that the terms `(n - k)!` and `k!` are in the denominator. Both issues can be fixed by writing

   ```
   bc <- function(n,k) return(fact(n)/(fact(n - k) * fact(k)))
   ```
3. To confirm, we calculate the coefficient for 5 choose 2:

   ```
   bc(5, 2)
   #10
   ```